# Support of a specific distribution

Tags: analysis

I am doing an exercise from a textbook, and it asks to find the support of the distribution given by

$$ T(\chi) = \int_\mathbb{R} \chi(x,-x)  dx$$

where $\chi \in C_c ^\infty (\mathbb{R^2})$.

While I understand that the support of a distribution is the complement of the largest open set where the distribution vanishes, I have no idea how to determine where this distribution might even vanish.

Could any one show me where the distribution vanishes to be able to determine its support?

Comment: This is integration along the line $x+y=0$ so I think the support is precisely this line.

Comment: The support should be a subset of $C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$